# Connection between the linear algebra and calculus explanation of linearity of the derivative operator

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, linear-transformations

This is too-embarrassing-to-ask question that keeps bothering me in the back of my mind:

It's clear that

$$D(f + g) = D(f) + D(g)$$

and that

$$ D(c f)= c D(f)$$

for $f, g$ differentiable functions and $c$ a scalar.

On the other hand we can construct the Jacobian matrix of partial derivatives, or a gradient and multiply it times a directional vector.

Or we can talk about the best linear approximation of a function, or the affine approximation, and it all makes sense independently.

But it bothers me that an operator that transforms nonlinear functions to other nonlinear functions (e.f. polynomials of grade $3$ to $2$) can be called linear. How are all the arguments reconciled with each other, and with the nonlinearity of the input functions being modified?

Comment: You need to look this from a slightly more abstract point of view. The linear operator only cares about the linear structur of the vector space, not what the objects of the vector space look like. For example I could identify $\mathbb{R}^3$ with the polynomials of degree at most two via the isomorphism $$\mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}[x]_{\leq 2}, (a,b,c)\mapsto a+bx+cx^2.$$ The LHS is something you think of as "linear", while you think of polynomials as something "nonlinear". However, we just look at the relation between them.

Comment: And not whether they are a nonlinear function of some mysterious variable $x$ that we introduced. Some for the derivative operator. It is linear on the space consisting of functions and doesn't care about the possibly nonlinear dependence on $x$.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven I see that and it's a nice and familiar explanation, but I still can't elegantly explain to myself why we are allowed not to care about the change from say a polynomial of grade 3 to a polynomial of grade 2 as a result of the linear operator of differentiation.

Comment: If you are familiar with the Fourier transform, you can also have a look at the following example: Every function in $L^2(S^1)$ (Sobolev space on the $1$d circle) can be written as a series of "plane waves" $$f(x) = \sum_{n\in \mathbb{Z}} a_n e^{2\pi i nx}.$$ This gives an isomorphism $$\ell^2(\mathbb{Z}, \mathbb{C}) \rightarrow L^2(S^1), (a_n)_{n\in \mathbb{Z}} \mapsto \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} a_n e^{2\pi i nx}.$$ Again, we take something "nonlinear", i.e. a function, and transform it into something  "linear". Now what does happen to the derivative in this setting?

Comment: Well the derivative of the plane wave picks up its "momentum" $$(e^{2\pi i n x})'= 2\pi i n e^{2\pi i nx}.$$ Thus, the derivative under this isomorphism becomes $$(a_n)_{n\in \mathbb{Z}} \mapsto (2\pi i n a_n)_{n\in \mathbb{Z}}.$$ Which is a nice linear operator.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven For instance, in your example $\mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}[x]_{\leq 2}, (a,b,c)\mapsto a+bx+cx^2$ it would all be understandable if the basis of the vector space remained unchanged $\{x^0, x^1, x^2\}.$ However, these change when the derivative operator is applied to $\{x^0, x^1\}.$ And this is the cue to introduce an $2\times 3$ matrix or row (dual) vector which is applied to to a $3 \times 1$ vector, yielding a $2 \times 1$ vector, I supposed... But it's all intuition. The only place where I "see" it is in polynomial regression, where the coefficients are hyperplanar

Comment: approximations to numbers that are simply squared or cubed, and that are just fed into the linear algebra machinery as though they were separate variables being measured.

Comment: The last example is over my head - I do understand Fourier transforms, but not the whole analytical underpinning (spaces).

Answer (score 4):

You need to review the definition of linearity from linear algebra, and differentiability, and clarify for yourself what exactly the adjective "linear" is describing. Let us fix an open set $U\subset\Bbb{R}^n$, a point $a\in U$, and let $\mathcal{D}_{a,U,\Bbb{R}^m}$ be the set of all functions $f:U\to\Bbb{R}^m$ which are differentiable at the point $a$. Also, let us use the notation $\mathcal{D}_{U,\Bbb{R}^m}$ to mean the set of all functions $f:U\to\Bbb{R}^m$ which are differentiable at every point of $U$. There are several layers of abstraction one has to learn to deal with.

- First, given $f\in\mathcal{D}_{a,U,\Bbb{R}^m}$, i.e a function differentiable at the point $a\in U$, the *derivative/differential at the point $a$* is a linear transformation $Df_a:\Bbb{R}^n\to\Bbb{R}^m$, i.e $Df_a\in\text{Hom}(\Bbb{R}^n,\Bbb{R}^m)$. The meaning of this linear transformation is that it is a first-order approximation of changes in your function:
  \begin{align}
  \Delta f_a(h):= f(a+h)-f(a)=Df_a(h)+o(\|h\|).
  \end{align}
  Said again, you're approximating the actual change, $\Delta f_a$, in the function at point $a$ by a linear function $Df_a$. Note that the function $\Delta f_a$ obviously need not be linear, whereas $Df_a$ is linear (by definition). Hence, this is called the linear approximation at point $a$, and this is why we say differential calculus is the study of local linear approximations.
- Next, there is the *derivative-at-point-$a$ operator*, which is the mapping $D(\cdot)_a:\mathcal{D}_{a,U,\Bbb{R}^m}\to\text{Hom}(\Bbb{R}^n,\Bbb{R}^m)$, $f\mapsto Df_a$. The fact that sum of differentiable functions, and scalar multiples are still differentiable means literally that the set $\mathcal{D}_{a,U,\Bbb{R}^m}$ (equipped with the usual pointwise addition and scalar multiplication for functions) is a vector space over $\Bbb{R}$. The target space of this mapping, $\text{Hom}(\Bbb{R}^n,\Bbb{R}^m)$, is again another vector space over $\Bbb{R}$. You have two real vector spaces, and a mapping between them. This is all you need to talk about linearity, and indeed, it is easily shown $f\mapsto Df_a$ is linear. The fact that this mapping is linear is a *bridge* between the obvious fact that $f\mapsto \Delta f_a$ is linear, and limiting properties (linear combinations of $o(\|h\|)$ functions are again $o(\|h\|)$). The fact that $f\mapsto Df_a$ is linear should not be confused with the fact that $Df_a$ is itself a linear transformation!
- Finally, we can elevate the discussion to differentiability at all points. We now have a mapping $D:\mathcal{D}_{U,\Bbb{R}^m}\to\text{Func}(U,\text{Hom}(\Bbb{R}^n,\Bbb{R}^m))$, $f\mapsto Df$. We're taking a differentiable function $f:U\to\Bbb{R}^m$ and outputting the function $Df:U\to\text{Hom}(\Bbb{R}^n,\Bbb{R}^m)$ (for each $a\in U$, we get $Df_a$ which itself is a linear transformation). Again, $\mathcal{D}_{U,\Bbb{R}^m}$ is a vector space, and the space of functions $\text{Func}(U,\text{Hom}(\Bbb{R}^n,\Bbb{R}^m))$ is another vector space, and we're saying that $D$ is a linear mapping between the two. We're saying that we can take one nonlinear function $f$, and output a completely different type of function, $Df$, which could still be non-linear, *BUT*, the manner in which this association takes place (i.e $f\mapsto Df$) remains linear.

If you have trouble wrapping around the idea that you can take nonlinear functions to non-linear functions, and still have that mapping be called linear, then it means you need to review/revise your linear algebra, and study things from the abstract vector space perspective (if you haven't already). *Linearity* itself is a very bare-bones concept requiring only the notion of a vector space over a field. Give me two vector spaces $V,W$ over a field $\Bbb{F}$, and I can tell you what it means for a function $T:V\to W$ to be linear (over $\Bbb{F}$). It absolutely does not matter what the individual elements of $V,W$ are. They could be numbers, they could be matrices, they could be polynomials, they could be functions, they could be some other wackadoodle object.

In my three bullet points above, the meaning of 'linearity' is always the same, but the objects whose linearity I'm referring to changes. This is something which you must be clear on.

Comment: This is just awesome! I'd say straight from The Book.

Comment: The second part of the penultimate paragraph seems intended to help me, so +1 for that and the obvious effort and erudition on the parts intended for a more selective audience. If I am not mistaken, on that part, you are basically referring to the opening conditions of the OP, aren't you?

Comment: @JAP yes I was referring to your first few statements in the OP, but also your final paragraph where you say you don't understand linearity vs non-linearity in the polynomial case. And yes, from the way you wrote things, I had suspicions that this answer may be slightly more advanced than what you're used to. However, I genuinely believe the stuff I said is basic, so not understanding it is merely a reflection of a lack of prerequisites (really only linear algebra), not that the concepts here are too abstract. So one should aim to fill in the gaps till what I said becomes "obvious" :)

Comment: anyway, the main takeaway here is to not use the word "linear" arbitrarily. You have to know linearity of *what*? Once you get over this hurdle, things are smooth sailing. btw the book I learnt linear algebra from is Friedberg Insel Spence (chapters 1,2 suffice for here). For multivariable calculus itself, my favourite text was Loomis and Sternberg (google it). They give you all the necessary linear algebra (you really only need the first few parts of chapters 1,2), and they also explain the differential calculus (chapter 3) as a direct non-linear generalization of linear algebra.

Comment: (Loomis and Sternberg is a rather abstract introduction, but also clearly written with a great many exercises to practice on, so I'd say well worth the effort)

Comment: My field could not be farther from math or physics, and my interest is curiosity. However, I wouldn't say that the formulation in mappings and homeomorphisms is the way this material is presented at a first encounter with linear algebra. Certainly not in the Lin Alg book you suggested, which gives a very basic example with cereals and vitamins in food. I do see, upon downloading, Friedberd's book that this is mentioned, and will look into it.